# Single Logout (SLO) via OpenID Connect

Tags: single-sign-on, experience-cloud, auth-provider, open-id-connect

We use an external identity provider to verify credentials with SSO via OpenID Connect to Salesforce Experience Cloud as the Relying Party. After the the person logs out from Site A, he should be logged from Salesforce as well:

1. User connects to Site A and logs in via external identity provider
2. User click on button X, he will be redirected to Experience Cloud *( after some verification )*
3. Logout from Site A

Expected: in step 4, user is logged out from Experience Cloud site

Comment: You have the right idea but the devil is in the details, including your other, non-Salesforce party. This makes it a not-so-great question for this forum. If you followed all the steps in [OIDC SLO](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_auth_slo_oidc_rp_configuring.htm&type=5), you should check if SLO is being correctly initiated when you "disconnect" from Site A.

Comment: How to do this? Read the [OIDC SLO spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html), then capture the trace, decode it and see if it matches the spec.  From there you might be able to say which party is at fault. If it appears to be a SF-side issue, you should open a support case.

Comment: i'm using Gravitee as SSO and gravitee doesn't support SLO ..